# JOGL program does not compile - javac with classpath

Tags: java, opengl, classpath, javac, jogl

I want to run a HelloWorld JOGL programm on the commandline. I downloaded the .jars from jogamp.org and put the

```
gluegen-rt.jar , 
jogl.all.jar , 
gluegen-java-src.zip , 
jogl-java-src.zip , 
gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar , 
jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar
```

in a directory "jar" in my HelloWorld folder  -  as described in 
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL .

Now I try to compile with

```
javac -classpath "jar/gluegen-rt.jar:jar/jogl.all.jar" HelloWorld.java
```

as described on https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE .

Then it throws me 14 errors starting with

```
HelloWorld.java:7: package javax.media.opengl does not exist
import javax.media.opengl.GL;
                         ^
```

When I try to compile with absolute paths using

```
javac -classpath "/Users/jonas/Desktop/cool_jogl/helloworld/jar/gluegen-rt.jar:/Users/jonas/Desktop/cool_jogl/helloworld/jar/jogl-all.jar" HelloWorld.java
```

it still throws me 12 errors starting with

```
HelloWorld.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GLCanvas
location: package javax.media.opengl
import javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas;
                         ^
```

Answer (score 2):

try to replace `javax.media` by `com.jogamp`

Answer (score 1):

You should use javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas
Some package names was changed. Use IDE autocomplete or look sources.zip to find new names.